# tableview update with new row keeping previous rows at first

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

After searching a lot did not found a proper solution to update a **tableview**

i want to update my tableview like a new coming record should place just below the previously updated records.

this is my code

```
if (sqlite3_open(myDatabase, &myConnection) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT  Description, SalePrice FROM ProductDetails WHERE Barcode = \'%@\'", barcode];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myConnection, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &sQLStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(sQLStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
                temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sQLStatement, 0)];
            }
            temp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
            if ([temp1 isEqualToString:@"0"])
            {temp1 = @"1";}
               temp2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sQLStatement, 1)]                    }
            }
            [description addObject: temp];
            [qty addObject: temp1];
            [price addObject:temp2];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sQLStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(myConnection);
}
myTable.hidden = NO;
myTable.delegate = self;
myTable.dataSource = self;
[myTable reloadData];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

and the tableview data source delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [description count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Configure the cell in each row
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

UILabel *lbl11 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
[lbl11 setText:@"Label1"];
UILabel *lbl21 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
[lbl21 setText:@"Label2"];
UILabel *lbl31 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
[lbl31 setText:@"Label3"];

lbl11.text = [description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
lbl21.text = [qty objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
lbl31.text = [price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

CGRect lbl11Rect = CGRectMake(20, 5, 450, 30);
CGRect lbl21Rect = CGRectMake(545, 5, 150, 30);
CGRect lbl31Rect = CGRectMake(795, 5, 150, 30);

UILabel *lbl11 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lbl11Rect];
lbl11.tag=1;
lbl11.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Superclarendon" size:15];
lbl11.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
//lbl11.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl11];

UILabel *lbl21 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lbl21Rect];
lbl21.tag=2;
lbl21.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Superclarendon" size:15];
lbl21.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
//lbl21.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl21];

UILabel *lbl31 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lbl31Rect];
lbl31.tag=3;
lbl31.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Superclarendon" size:15];
lbl31.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
//lbl31.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl31];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
return cell;
}
```

for first value search it showed the data in tableview…. how can i update tableview properly
i have found that for update

```
[myTable beginUpdate]
```

function will be used… and there is also

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation
```

but unfortunately didn't find any good help that how to use this.
any help will be appreciated ….

Comment: first of all you not doing deque the cells properly. after deque the cell you are again initialising the cell in getCellContent view which is wrong.

Comment: @faiziii will you plz tell me the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First update your data source so numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath will return the correct values for your post-insert data. You must do this before you insert or delete rows.
Then insert your row:

```
   // First figure out how many sections there are
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;

// Then grab the number of rows in the last section
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex];

// Now just construct the index path
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

//Adding new data row to last index position:
[myTable beginUpdates];
[myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: pathToLastRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[myTable endUpdates];
```

There are different variants for animation:

```
UITableViewRowAnimationBottom
UITableViewRowAnimationFade
UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle
UITableViewRowAnimationNone
UITableViewRowAnimationRight
UITableViewRowAnimationTop
```

From iOs Developer Library:

```
beginUpdates
Begin a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the receiver.
Discussion
Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously. This group of methods must conclude with an invocation of endUpdates. These method pairs can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid. You should not call reloadData within the group; if you call this method within the group, you will need to perform any animations yourself.
```

The example of using this method you can find in Related Sample Code: **iPhoneCoreDataRecipes**

Comment: will you please tell me where should i place this code according to my code … i am few days developer in iOS so i don't know exactly what u are suggesting me…

Comment: @Zaibi look my updating answer